# read data from internet

Tags: r

I have a remote folder on a webserver containing data.
I access the data using:

`myData <-read.table("http://.../myData.csv", sep=',', header=T)`

Is there a way to password protect the remote folder and enter the authorisation in the above command?

Thx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the [RCurl](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html) package:

```
require("RCurl")
read.table(textConnection(getURL("http://.../data.csv",
                                 userpwd = "user:pass")),
           sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: If you feel this answers the question you could click on the tick by the answer to accept it ;)

Comment: This is also proving more robust than vanilla url() via the read.table() function.  I was having an issue where certain http server error calls were causing http connections to hang in a CLOSE_WAIT state.  I would guess that read.table() was not properly closing the connection on its own, even when a stop() command was used in a try block.  The Rcurl equivalent like what you show here does in fact close the connections properly, which is great.  Kudos.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you can embed usernames and passwords in the URL, like so:

http://username:pass@myserver.org/path/to/file.dat

Comment: To be precise, it is not that R is just trying to connect to this address, it is just a convention how performing HTTP/FTP/... auth is implemented, and indeed it is used by many programs, also R. But, for instance, web browsers tend behave strange with it due to the security reasons.